# ¿Cómo cifrar y descifrar datos usando PHP?

Tags: php

Necesito poder cifrar datos, solo es información simple, nada de que preocuparse en temas de seguridad, esta información cifrada necesito pasarla por método `GET`, por ejemplo:

```
example.com/?dato=aHDwbejferbdscb23zs
```

Entonces para esto estoy utilizando `openssl_encrypt` y `openssl_decrypt` teniendo lo siguiente:

```
$url = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
$key_encrypt = '1234567812345678';
$iv = '1234567812345678';
$encrypt = openssl_encrypt($url, "AES-128-CBC", $key_encrypt, FALSE, $iv);
$decrypt = openssl_decrypt($encrypt, "AES-128-CBC", $key_encrypt, FALSE, $iv);
```

El problema es que este cifrado me puede crear caracteres especiales, por ejemplo:

```
ncG1vNJzZmihkW19coCPcGWuq16Wv6S0yK%2BcZ6einHx2e8itnKarX2d9dquRaWlqaGdng3B%2Bj25lopleor11==
```

Y, al pasar esta información por método `GET`, no voy poder descifrar dicha información por dichos caracteres.

Entonces, la pregunta es la siguiente, existe la posibilidad de que el cifrado no sea tan largo, esto es opcional. Lo que si requiero es que el cifrado solo sea de `a-Z` y números `0-9` sin que se agregue caracteres especiales que perjudique la comprobación por método `GET`

Comment: Puedes codificar usando [Base64](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: @Sal Si es este https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.base64-encode.php igual genera al final == incluso fallo en unas ocasiones, aunque en el mismo ejemplo de salida se observa al final ==

Comment: Se acostumbra una versión para url, sólo es cambiar `+` por `-` y `/` por `_`, y el de relleno `=` simplemente lo quitas. De hecho, los primeros comentarios en la documentación se refieren a eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar la librería JWT  que convierte un array  a string(JSON) el cual se puede pasar por URL

Aquí tienes la documentación y la libreria [JWT](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt)

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo

```html
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

//llave de encriptacion
$key = "example_key";

//datos a enviar 
$payload = array(
    "iss" => "http://example.org",
    "aud" => "http://example.com",
    "iat" => 1356999524,
    "nbf" => 1357000000
);

//encriptadmos
$jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $key);


//Esta es la variable que enviaras en el URL
print_r($jwt);

//asi es como se desencripta 

$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
```